# Screen gets cut off when moved from laptop to monitor Javascript/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, view

When I move my window from my laptop to my monitor, I have to refresh  the page because it maintains the view size and displays white for the lower half of the page.

How can I detect I have moved my window to another screen and change the page scaling accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

How is your UI drawn? Via Javascript or via HTML/CSS?

Solution for Javascript:
When moving the window (being a maximized windows) it tries to resize itself 
to fit. You can detect this change of size using the [window.onresize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize)-Eventhandler.

Here is an example:

```
window.onresize = __resize;
function __resize() { 
   var h = window.innerHeight;
   var w = window.innerWidth;
}
```

Note: You need to implement a function which redraws your UI once the new size has been determined.

Solution for HTML/CSS: Just implement a responsive design. Here are good information about this topic: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp